# Cartesian product of a list of sets in python

Tags: python, python-itertools

I had a list of sets. I do not know the length of the list apriori. I wanted to find the Cartesian product of the sets in the list in some code I'm writing.

For example:
I have

```
list_of_sets=[set(['A']),set(['A','B','C']), set('D','E')];
```

I want to output a cartesian product of these sets, which would be,

```
('A', 'A', 'E')
('A', 'A', 'D')
('A', 'C', 'E')
('A', 'C', 'D')
('A', 'B', 'E')
('A', 'B', 'D')
```

If I knew that the list had size 3 in advance, I could use the following code to generate this cartesian product.

```
for i in itertools.product(list_of_sets[0],list_of_sets[1],list_of_sets[2]):
    print i
```

Is there an easy way to do this when I do not know the size of the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `itertools.product(*list_of_sets)`.